# ValidationRule For Account Name REGEX format

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, regular-expressions

How can I create a Validation rule for Text field (Account Name) REGEX Format. Example Format: Raja Sekhar$9

Comment: Is that your whole post? What is the pattern that you want to enforce?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm), it explains quite well how to use the `REGEX` function:

> **REGEX**
>
> **Description**
> Compares a text field to a regular expression and returns TRUE if there is a match. Otherwise, it returns FALSE. A regular expression is a string used to describe a format of a string according to certain syntax rules.
>
> **Use**
> REGEX(text, regex_text) and replace text with the text field, and regex_text with the regular expression you want to match.

So if you want to validate the `Name` field to disallow a string, it would look like:

```
REGEX(Name, '<expression>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Raja Sekhar I will explain with you a sample example.so you can modify with your requirements.We have secuirty number in a custom object the format [xxx-xx-xxxx] like below.

```
NOT(OR(ISBLANK(Security_Number__c),REGEX( Security_Number__c , "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]
                 {2}-[0-9]{4}")))
```